# Batch file for copying every nth file from folder1 to folder2?

Tags: windows, file, powershell, batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy every 30th file from one folder to another and automate the process for other folders. I have already tried the batch script in this thread: [windows batch file script to copy every tenth file from a folder to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560371/windows-batch-file-script-to-copy-every-tenth-file-from-a-folder-to-another-fold) and just get "The syntax in that command is incorrect" when I run the file (and yes, I've tried both versions).

My folders do have spaces in the names (not my choice and cannot be changed). The files are named image00000X.jpg and yes, there are over 100k of them (which is why I really want the script to work).

Ideally, I'd like a way to set the script up so that I could just change the input and output paths and not have to move the script between the different folders when running it but I'll settle for whatever I can get at this point because I have tried just about everything else (including robocopy, Xcopy, five Powershell scripts, and a few BASH scripts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple batch file:

```
:: copyNth.bat  interval  sourcePath  destinationPath
@echo off
setlocal
set /a n=0
for %%F in ("%~f2.\*") do 2>nul set /a "1/(n=(n+1)%%%1)" || copy "%%F" %3
```

sampleUsage:

```
copyNth 30 "c:\someSourcePath" "d:\someDestinationPath"
```

The `"%~f2.` is [syntax that allows you to safely append a file (or file mask) to any provided path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26702311/1012053).

The trick to getting every Nth value is to let SET /A intentionally raise a division by 0 error. I redirect the error message to nul and conditionally copy the file only when there was an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use just a standard `for` loop.  I added some params as well, so you can change the source, destination, and skip count on the fly:

```
param(
    [string]$Source = $( throw "You Must Specify Source Directory" ),
    [string]$Destination = $( throw "You Must Specify Destination Directory" ),
    [int]$Skip = 30
)

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File

for( $idx = 0; $idx -lt $Files.count; $idx += $Skip ) {
    $Files[$idx] | Move-Item -Destination $Destination
}
```

`Source` and `Destination` are required params, but `Skip` defaults to 30 if you don't specify a value.  To use, name it something like `move30th.ps1`, and run it like:

```
.\move30th.ps1 -Source "C:\Path\To\Files" -Destination "C:\New\Path" -Skip 30
```

Comment: Hi Hunter, 

Following your directions just causes the file to open up in Notepad. I copied your code exactly as is, named the file exactly as you suggested, ran it using the same command -- altering only the path values -- and it just pops open Notepad with the move30th.ps1 file code in it. No files are copied or moved between the two specified directories.

At least it's a different error than the others I've been getting.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run it from a cmd.exe window (the default action for a PS1 file is to open in notepad).  Try running it from a powershell.exe window instead.

Comment: Thanks! That wasn't the exact problem but it did lead me to finding the real issue -- when I updated PowerShell a few weeks ago, my policies all got wiped out from AllSigned/RemoteSigned to Undefined which meant that every script was failing. Setting them back correctly just now got your script to run beautifully.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple Do/While loop like:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem C:\Path\To\Files
$i = 0
Do{
    $files[$i]|Move-Item -Dest C:\New\Path
    $i=$i+30
}While($i -le $files.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python you could do something like this.

```
    import glob
    import shutil

    files = glob.glob("data/set1/*.png")
    n = 30

    for file in files[0::n]:
        shutil.move(file, "data/set3")
```