# windows batch file script to copy every fourth file from a folder to another folder

Tags: file, copy

I came across this thread [Windows Batch Script for Copy Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560371/windows-batch-file-script-to-copy-every-tenth-file-from-a-folder-to-another-fold#new-answer?newreg=005ab4e7bc924546859ce5ce568b33fd) for copying .text files. My case is almost identical, except I'm dealing with .JPG files. I've tried the answer from the thread without success.

In my case, I have 827 jpg files in a folder and I want to select every fourth file (i.e. 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, etc. file) according to name/alphabetical arrangement of the files and copy them to another folder. The files have been named in sequence by the camera, DSC00018 to DSC00844.

This is the code that I tried to use, and got "The syntax of the command is incorrect" message.

```
@echo off
set Counter=0
for %%f in (*.jpg) do call :p "%%f"
goto :eof

:p
    set /a Counter+=1
    set /a X=Counter %% 4
    if %X%==0 copy %1 C:\Documents\New folder
goto :eof
```

Maybe it has something to do with Windows 7 Pro shows JPG file without .ext file type? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the folder path "C:\Documents\New folder" and make sure the folder you want to copy the images to has been created already before you run the script.